# How to use both ON DUPLICATE KEY and REPLACE INTO in the same query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table like this:

```
// AcceptedAnswer
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
| id | user_id | question_id | answer_id |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | 123     | 4335345     | 3342434   |
| 2  | 345     | 4565546     | 3443565   |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+

// user_id : the id of that person who is author of question
```

Also I have a **unique**-index-group on these three columns: `(user_id, question_id, answer_id)`.

There is three cases:

- When there isn't any accepted answer and OP (`user_id`) wants to accept an asnwer.
- When there is an accepted answer and OP wants to undo it.
- When there is an accepted answer and OP wants to change it to another answer.

My script works for first two cases as well. But it doesn't work for third case. How can I implement that?

Here is my script:

```
try {

    // DB connection here

    // This SELECT statement validates whether user_id is the author of the question     
    $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO AcceptedAnswer(user_id, question_id, answer_id)
                              SELECT ?,?,?
                              FROM questions q
                              WHERE q.id = ? and q.author_id = ? limit 1;");

    $stmt->execute( array( $_SESSION["Id"], $question_id, $answer_id,
                           $question_id, $_SESSION["Id"] ) );


} catch(PDOException $e) {

    // undo acceptance
    if ((int) $e->getCode() === 23000) {
    $stmt = $dbh_conn->prepare(" DELETE FROM AcceptedAnswer
                                 WHERE user_id = ? AND
                                       question_id = ? AND
                                       answer_id = ? ");
    $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION["Id"], $question_id, $answer_id));

}
```

---

**For example:** *(based on table above)*

When I pass this: `(123, 4335345, 2353423)` *(changing accepted answer)*, Expected output:

```
// AcceptedAnswer
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
| id | user_id | question_id | answer_id |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | 123     | 4335345     | 2353423   |
| 2  | 345     | 4565546     | 3443565   |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

When I pass this: `(345, 4565546, 3443565)` *(undo accepted answer)*, Expected output:

```
// AcceptedAnswer
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
| id | user_id | question_id | answer_id |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | 123     | 4335345     | 2353423   |
+----+---------+-------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot combine these two queries, as they are mutual exclusive.

Besides, you don't seem to need a REPLACE INTO at all.

In fact, you need only two queries, one is INSERT with ON DUPLICATE to accept whatever answer, and one is delete - to unaccept.

Also, instead of exception handling, I would use  just a simple condition to see whether it was accept or unaccept sent from the form.

Note that you should have an else clause in your if condition indide catch block, to **rethrow** an exception if it was not one expected.